# add ' to front of string from vector

Tags: php, regex, r, vector

I need to print the results from a html parsing into an PHP array.  I am stuck at the very last part.

```
    library(XML)
    url ='http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/authors/j/john_kenneth_galbraith.html'
    page <- htmlParse(url)
    quote <- xpathSApply(page, 
  "//text()[not(ancestor::script)][not(ancestor::style)][not(ancestor::noscript)][not(ancestor::form)]", 
  xmlValue)
    quote = quote[nchar(quote) > 50] # this removes all none quotes based on string length
quote = quote[1:(length(quote)-2)]  # this drops the last 
    out = paste(quote, collaspe= "', ") # how to get the ' at the front of the quote
    write(out, "quote.txt")
```

The final code has the text string with --- quote here---',(apostrophe  - comma) at the end. I need to put the '(apostrophe) at the beginning and do not have idea how to do it.  I tried using r to json but does not work for simple php array I use. which is structure like this:

```
<?php
$quotes = array('quote goes here', 'quote goes here', 'final quote');
$rand = rand( 0, count($quotes)-1 );
echo $quotes[$rand];
?>
```

I do not really use php but it just runs on everything so I did this random quote maker is simple terms.  I could rewrite in javascript and use a json array. But I would then need to write in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the extraction somewhat (maybe this takes care of your apostrophe etc ?)

```
library(XML)
url ='http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/authors/j/john_kenneth_galbraith.html'
page <- htmlParse(url)
out <- sapply(page['//span[@class="bqQuoteLink"]/a'], xmlValue)
write(out, "quote.txt")

> head(paste0("'", out, "'"))
[1] "'The modern conservative is engaged in one of man's oldest exercises in moral philosophy; that is, the search for a superior moral justification for selfishness.'"                                                        
[2] "'Economics is extremely useful as a form of employment for economists.'"                                                                                                                                                   
[3] "'All of the great leaders have had one characteristic in common: it was the willingness to confront unequivocally the major anxiety of their people in their time. This, and not much else, is the essence of leadership.'"
[4] "'In economics, the majority is always wrong.'"                                                                                                                                                                             
[5] "'Faced with the choice between changing one's mind and proving that there is no need to do so, almost everyone gets busy on the proof.'"                                                                                   
[6] "'Under capitalism, man exploits man. Under communism, it's just the opposite.'"
```

Comment: That simplifies the extraction nicely but does not help me in preparing the final output, unfortunately.  But thank you I see I did things the hard way in extracting the text.

Comment: I think I can do something using cat and paste but still can not get it to output:  cat( paste('"', out, '",', "\n", sep=""))

Comment: Maybe you want `head(paste0("'", out, "'"))`?